# Formatting/ingesting text in Google Docs and Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a giant Google Docs that looks like this:

```
...
this is a line with some text, 1
this is a line with some more text, 1
here is another line with some text, 0
here is another line with some text, 1
here is yet another line with text, 0
and finally here is a line with text, 1
...
```

The lines with text can be anywhere from a few words to a few paragraphs. However, they always end in either a `1` or `0`. These lines were taken from a spreadsheet, and I can access them as text block in a cell with an adjacent column containing `1` or `0`.

The Excel would look something like:

```
-----------------
block of text | 0
block of text | 1
block of text | 0
block of text | 0
block of text | 1
------------------
```

The problem I face:

```
Everything with a `1` should be right aligned on this document.
Everything with a `0` should be left aligned on this document.
```

I'm hoping there is a way to do this (either my writing a function/using a tool on the spreadsheet or selecting relevant text in the document). I suspect trying to select the lines in the document may be more difficult, since some text blocks span multiple paragraphs but only have one numeric indicator.

Comment: Are you using excel as a synonym of spreadsheet? Did you already search this site for similar questions? Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The following [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) takes the values from the range A1:B4 of the currently active sheet, and uses them to fill a new document (called Test Document) in the specified way. Each entry from column A is added as a paragraph, and aligned according to column B (zero entry = left, nonzero = right).

If you want to modify an existing document, use `var doc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID_GOES_HERE');` instead of the first line of this function.

```
function alignParagraphs() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Test Document');
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:B4");
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    body.appendParagraph(values[i][0])
    .setAlignment(values[i][1] ? DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT : DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Paste from Excel into Sheets (as columns A:B). Filter to select `0` in ColumnB and align left. Change filter to select `1` in ColumnB and align right. Results shown in ColumnsD:E:

[image: WA100848 first example]

Copy/Paste into Docs for result:

[image: WA100848 second example]